# NODE.JS: How can I return value from this nested function?

Tags: node.js

```
function authenticateUser(un, pwd){
  users.find({username: un}).toArray((err, items) => {
    try{
      bcrypt.compare(pwd, items[0].password, function(err, result) {
      // i want to return this result
    });}catch (error){
      console.log("")
      // in this case i want to return false
    }
  })
}
```

How can I return data from this nested function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use data from async function out of it's own scope. You can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323) on SO to better understand how async calls work.

You can update your code to make it work.

```
function authenticateUser(un, pwd, callback) {
    users.find({
        username: un
    }).toArray((err, items) => {
        bcrypt.compare(pwd, items[0].password, (err, isMatch) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
            callback(null, isMatch);
        })
    })
}
```

Then when you want to use this function you can use it like this

```
authenticateUser(user, enteredPassword, (err, isMatch) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
            if (isMatch) {
                console.log(`YAY Password Matched`);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use promises to do this.

```
function authenticateUser(un, pwd){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      users.find({username: un}).toArray((err, items) => {
      if (err) reject(err);

       bcrypt.compare(pwd, items[0].password, function(err, result) {
       if (err) reject(err);
       resolve(result);
       // i want to return this result
     })
    })
 })
}


async function main() {
   try {
     const result = await authenticateUser(un, pwd);
     console.log(result);
  } catch(e) {
     console.error(e);
  }
}
```

How to work with async/await check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Note: `try/catch` doesn't work with callbacks.